# Multiple Domains to Single Site & IP in IIS7

Tags: iis-7, dns, ip

The server I have at my disposal has only 1 IP available and I'm trying to host multiple domains/applications. As known DNS records will not allow sub directories, so this has to be handled through IIS. I found some information online about this topic but not anything solid for IIS 7.

From what I've read this can be achieved elegantly through the use of HTTP/Host Headers. I'd like to avoid using redirects or URL Rewriting. If you're familiar with this topic or other workaround and can provide some instructions on settings this up it would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a host name under the binding in IIS 7. Note that you cannot do this with HTTPS binding.

[image]

In your case, you would select the IP address (or leave it as All Unassigned), and for your host name enter it, such as "mysite1.com". In a different website, do the same thing except use that host name, such as "mysite2.com".

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I feel a bit silly having overlooked that :)